# How to optimize time taken for retrieving gems using bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

How to optimize time taken for retrieving gems using bundle, since we are on a poor internet connection we get such errors often on a bundle install. Is there a way to share gem downloads within the LAN environment.

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip-3.5.4.gem)

Comment: Appreciate any inputs on this